# Using Range.Find For Cells in Another Worksheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

I'm trying to use range.Find to find the cell in another sheet that contains a string input on a previous sheet (I'm searching for a column header in a table so I won't have to update my macro if columns get shifted around). I'm using the function below, but I always get an error saying that an Object is Required. I've looked at similar topics and tried their methods, but what works for them just isn't working for me. How can I use Range.Find to find the cell that a column header is in in a different sheet? Here's the code I'm using:

```
Function FindColumn(ByVal name as String) As Range
    'cds is the other worksheet I need to find the column header in
    Set FindColumn = cds.Range("A1:AA1").Find(name) 
    If FindColumn Is Nothing Then MsgBox(name & " Not Found!")
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, `cds` would appear to be `Nothing`, which could contribute to that error. Is `cds` assigned a worksheet object elsewhere in your code?  If so, what is that variable's scope?  If it is not module or public, then that would explain it.

If it is module/public, ensure that the variable `cds` is assigned *prior* to calling the function.

If it is a procedure-level variable, you will need to pass it to the function like:

```
FindColumn "columnname", cds
```

And modify the function to accept this additional argument:

```
Function FindColumn(byVal name as String, cds as Worksheet)
```

Comment: Oh wow... I've been programming in C++ for years... it kinda hurts to get stumped on a scope issue. It works just fine now though. Thanks a ton!

Comment: no worries! Sometimes you just need another set of eyes to notice what should be obvious :)

Comment: I think the biggest issue was that the error I was getting wasn't an undefined variable error but rather an object required error. But hey at least it works! :)

Comment: You won't get an undefined error unless you use `Option Explicit` at the top of each module (which BTW you should be doing!).  Unless you do that, VBA allows implicit variable declaration and undeclared variables will be of type `Variant` -- without testing it I am pretty sure this raises the "Object required" error, either because you're trying to assign *to* an object variable (FindColumn is a Range object) from something that is not an object, or you're trying to access a property/method (`cds.Range`) of a variable that is not an object type.